# VBA Compilation Error (1004 Automation Error)

Tags: vba, excel, module

I am trying to write a program which would take the information from a user selected grid and the information adjacent to it and send them to another workbook. However, whenever I compile, I would get the error 1004 (Automation). Can someone please point out where I have made a mistake in my code? It will be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CopyItemsByLocation()

Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim wsThis As Worksheet
Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
Dim strName  As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range

Set wbThis = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsThis = ActiveSheet

strName = ActiveSheet.Name

Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Excel Testing\Excel Info Testing 2.xlsx")
Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(strName)

Set rng1 = Selection

For i = 1 To 4
    If i = 1 Then
    wsThis.Range(rng1).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("E5") **'<~Error occurs here**
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

    ElseIf i = 2 Then
    wsThis.Range(rng1).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("G5")
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

    ElseIf i = 3 Then
    wsThis.Range(rng1).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("I5")
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

    Else
    wsThis.Range(rng1).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("K5")
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(0, 1)

    End If
    Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close

Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbThis = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rng1` is already a range so

```
wsThis.Range(rng1).Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("E5")
```

should be

```
rng1.Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("E5")
```

Also might want to set `rng1` *before* opening the other workbook
Reworked a bit:

```
Sub CopyItemsByLocation()

    Const WB As String = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Excel Testing\Excel Info Testing 2.xlsx"
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range

    Set rng1 = Selection.Cells(1) 'in case of >1 cell selected

    Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open(WB)
    Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets(rng1.Parent.Name)

    rng1.Copy wsTarget.Range("E5")
    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Copy wsTarget.Range("G5")
    rng1.Offset(0, 2).Copy wsTarget.Range("I5")
    rng1.Offset(0, 3).Copy wsTarget.Range("K5")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    wbTarget.Save
    wbTarget.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly the problem
Have a nice day :)